# Fedora: Can I Install Fedora 13 without the Gnome Desktop?

Tags: linux, installation, fedora

I have a CD with the standard 64-bit version of Fedora 13. I want to install it on a VirtualBox VM for local web development testing. How can I install it **without** Gnome and all the extra content that goes along with the Gnome environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During installation I watched for an opportunity to modify the packages to be installed, but I never saw it. I'm sure I just missed it; however I did notice a few people saying that they'd tried blocking X/Gnome from installation but it installed them anyway. Something about Fedora being intended as a Desktop environment, not a Server. Go figure.

At any rate, I had to just uninstall them after the OS was completely installed, and once that was done I still had to change the default runlevel. Talk about a pain, but at least it's working.

Answer (score 4):

http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Installation_Quick_Start_Guide/images/pkgselection/pkg-group.png Select Customize now (at the bottom) and than remove the Gnome/KDE and the xserver package.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just ignore all Gnome, KDE, and X packages on install. I don't remember all of the specifics off the top of my head. You could also install Fedora regularly and then use runlevels to just boot into CLI only mode. More information can be found here: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=89849

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Gnome LiveCD - the short answer is that you probably can't (or at least you'll have to install, and the uninstall Gnome.

The LiveCD has a fixed configuration that it copies over to the hard drive, and isn't truly an install CD/DVD.

Comment: I think you're probably right about that. This would explain why I never had the option to modify my package selections -- I was using the LiveCD installer.

Answer (score 0):

while installation dont choose Xserver

Answer (score 0):

if you are after a headless / commandline version of Linux (which uses yum or redhat / fedora like) install CentOS.

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/centos-netinstall-network-installation/

Comment: I'm looking for complete compatibility with our current server environment, which uses Fedora 13. Just don't need the extra overhead of Gnome in the VM. And yes, I realize CentOS is basically the same platform but I just don't want to deal with any unexpected configuration differences.

Comment: you use Fedora 13 as a server environment? You are aware that it will be maintained for approximately another 7 months and after that you're on your own: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/LifeCycle#Maintenance_Schedule.

Comment: I certainly didn't choose Fedora myself. I would have gone with CentOS. But the folks who setup our server chose Fedora, and now that we've fully migrated that's what I'm stuck with.

Comment: By the way, whomever down-voted this answer really wasted a rep point. It's a perfectly valid answer, just not quite the one I was looking for.